# Cannot connect to mysql image by linking in docker compose file

Tags: mysql, django, docker, docker-compose

I am using the following docker-compose file

```
version: '2'
services:
 app_test:
  build:
   context: .
   dockerfile: Dockerfile-jenkins-test
  ports:
   - "7200:7200"
  volumes:
   - .:/opt/project
  environment:
   - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myapp.settings.test
   - MYSQL_DATABASE=test_db
   - DB_HOST=mysql_test_db
   - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my_pass
   - DB_PORT=3306
  links:
   - mysql_test_db
 mysql_test_db:
  image: mysql:latest
  container_name: mysql_db_container
  expose:
   - "3306"
  environment:
   - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypass
   - MYSQL_DATABASE=test_db
```

when trying to access the mysql using the DB_HOST mysql_test_db it will gives an error saying

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host
>   'mysql_test_db' (0)")

How to access the linked MySQL db image from app_test?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need "links" of that kind, all services in docker-compose can reach themselfs and are "linked" automatically using their service name.

There is also no need to expose 3306, since in the internal docker-network for that docker-compose stack, the port can be reached by any service inside the network anyway.

```
version: '2'
services:
 app_test:
  build:
   context: .
   dockerfile: Dockerfile-jenkins-test
  ports:
   - "7200:7200"
  volumes:
   - .:/opt/project
  environment:
   - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myapp.settings.test
   - MYSQL_DATABASE=test_db
   - DB_HOST=mysql_test_db
   - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my_pass
   - DB_PORT=3306
 mysql_test_db:
  image: mysql:latest
  container_name: mysql_db_container
  environment:
   - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypass
   - MYSQL_DATABASE=test_db
```

But what you are dealing with most probably is, that ht order of service-starts does not suit you. Mysql will need a while before the DB can be connected and is provisioned with the credentials, while your django app is firing up very fast and tries to connect instantly, before those credentials have been provisioned.

You need, in your entry-point of you django app, to use something like wait-for-it https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it and test that the 3306 port is available. In MSQYL terms, this could even be falsy, since the provision starts with a mysqld_safe daemon, not allowing any connections, but the TCP socket is open and will fool "wait for it".

So what you can do is using a real mysql-connection using your credentials to block the app from booting until the connection can be established:

```
#!/bin/bash

RET=1
echo "Waiting for database"
while [[ RET -ne 0 ]]; do
    sleep 1;
    if [ -z "${db_password}" ]; then
        mysql -h $db_host -u $db_user -e "select 1" > /dev/null 2>&1; RET=$?
    else
        mysql -h $db_host -u $db_user -p$db_password -e "select 1" > /dev/null 2>&1; RET=$?
    fi
done
echo "DB reached, continuing"
```

So this happens right before you actually bootstrap your django app.

That should help - and also should help what level of issues, several levels, can be the cause here.

Comment: unfortunately I am trying this out using a Jenkins Pipeline and cannot use a real connection there

Comment: You do need linking otherwise it will b troublesome in multi branch pipeline environments

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with pipelines, neither have pipelines anything to do with real or unreal connections - setting the project name to the branch name for composer is the proper way to namespace, beside there are namespaced anyway. Linking local services with the same name as the service is complete nonsense. You can link to rename local services or you link external ones

Comment: I really doubt on that, you might face deadlocks with shared resources. Anyway thank you for your answer